# How to save and restore WPFToolkit DataGrid columns layout to XML?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

WPFTookit has number of slick features. However, I am trying to find a way to save and restore its columns layout into xml. The .NET stock DataGrid has DataGridColumn.DisplayIndex and ColumnIndex properties that enable this functionality, as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37087/DataGridView-that-Saves-Column-Order-Width-and-Vis). How to do this for WPFToolkit's DataGrid ?

I tried this [snippet](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfDataGrid/Code_Snippets_Persisting_Settings.html) from XCeed documentation, but apparently XCeed.Wpf.DataGrid.Settings.SettingsRepository has been removed.

Sample code is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of the toolkit are you using?

Comment: @netniV : I have the latest one, v2.5.0 http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/ . Which one do you have ? I can adjust it since it is a greenfield project.

Comment: I have the sources to that one so won't be a problem. Will take a look in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I went and looked at the basic documentation, didn't see the functions there.  So, I went and checked through source history to see if it was in there and it wasn't.

Knowing that they have paid and free versions of the toolkit, I thought I'd look at the DataGrid for that too.  Whilst I didn't see it on the main Xceed website, I did find that it turns out those features are only available with the [Advanced DataGrid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced%20DataGrid#persistusersettings).

So this means that you would need to implement your own custom save/restore settings rather than relying on their functions.

**EDIT**

*HINT: All of the columns should have a VisibilePosition*